# How can I make two elements that are next to each other in a flex row go on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm learning how to make more responsive designs and I'm trying to design a program that's going to simulate a game of the card game war. I want the `h3` for the score to be underneath the `h2` for both players. I've got the program designed the way I'd like it to look on smart phones, but not on tablets or desktops. I'm still very very early into learning all of this so I apologize if this question isn't structured as well as it could be. Here's my code:

```
body {
  background-color: #00512c;
}

.playing-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 95vh;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.playing-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.player {
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.score {
  font-family: "popins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #da1212;
  border-radius: 25%;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #b22727;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 549px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .playing-card {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .playing-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  } 
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>War</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="playing-field">
      <h2 class="player">Player 1</h2>
      <h3 class="score score-1">Score: 0</h3>
      <div class="card card-0">
        <img class="playing-card" src="PNG-cards-1.3/10_of_clubs.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <button class="btn">Draw</button>

      <div class="card card-1">
        <img
          class="playing-card"
          src="PNG-cards-1.3/10_of_diamonds.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <h2 class="player">Player 2</h2>
      <h3 class="score score-2">Score: 0</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By responsive, i think you can read more on the CSS Units [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) as it helps to use relative sizing for the CSS properties such as width, margin, padding, font-size, etc. For the `h3` under the `h2`, example here i just added a `div` to each so the player and score stays together. Im unsure if this is what youre looking for but i hope it helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: #00512c;
}

.playing-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  width: 30vh;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.playing-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vh;
  min-height: 30vh;
}

.player {
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.score {
  font-family: "popins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #da1212;
  border-radius: 25%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #b22727;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 549px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .playing-card {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .playing-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>War</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="playing-field">
      <div class="player">
        <h2 class="player1">Player 1</h2>
        <h3 class="score score-1">Score: 0</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-0">
        <img class="playing-card" src="PNG-cards-1.3/10_of_clubs.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <button class="btn">Draw</button>

      <div class="card card-1">
        <img
          class="playing-card"
          src="PNG-cards-1.3/10_of_diamonds.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div class="player">
      <h2 class="player2">Player 2</h2>
      <h3 class="score score-2">Score: 0</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```